# Set 24-hour clock format in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, locale, time-format

Despite the fact that in `http://<jenkins server>/systemInfo` the `user.timezone` property value meets my actual time zone I still have 12-hour clock format.

[image]

I would like to have 24-hour clock format instead.

Does anyone have any ideas how it can be changed in Jenkins?

Thank you.

Comment: Jenkins uses the browsers language, if you have it set to english (US) then change it to english (GB)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As @Arkain mentioned, you should specify in browser's settings the language which suits your intended time format. I had both `English (US)` and just `English` (which I thought was English (GB)), but then I realized that I should have added additional `English (GB)` language.

Thank you!

Comment: Hmm, this seems to work only on the individual job pages, not on the pipeline view, at least with Jenkins 1.554.1.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann I believe that time format settings are applied for the whole Jenkins unless Pipeline plugin has it own settings. And yes, as a last resort you can try newer version of Jenkins.

Comment: @Jonny, please notice that the answer is about specifying a language in the browser, not the clock format. The time format is affected as a result of changing a language.

Comment: i tried setting US and DE web page selections in google chrome. it worked nicely on e.g. the Google search page but not at all for the Build History column of a Jenkins 2.235.5 install.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, this situation hasn't changed and Jenkins' date display style is still linked to the browser language as of January 2016.

On a sidenote: There's a [Locale Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Locale+Plugin), which supposedly allows to override Jenkins' default behaviour of picking up the locale via the browser language. Although - as [Greg Dubicki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2693875) noted - this plugin [does process a `language_country_variant` string](https://github.com/jenkinsci/locale-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/locale/PluginImpl.java#L82), only the language part (a 2-digit [ISO 639-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-1) [language code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes)) has an effect, and it's only defining the UI langauge. The date display format still seems to be defined solely by the browser's language.

Comment: Actually Locale Plugin should accept and use "en_GB" setting correctly, according to its code: https://github.com/jenkinsci/locale-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/locale/PluginImpl.java#L82 ... But in my case it doesn't. :(

Comment: Btw: "en_IE" locale would be a safer bet to get English & 24h-format, see: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62316/why-is-there-no-euro-english-locale

Comment: for e.g. Ubuntu desktop or Windows:
language of the UI is one item.
date/time and currency formats are a separate item.
sometimes dealing with them in a joint fashion can help solving some defaults. but sometimes you definitely want to override that. (BTW time zone is also something separate.)